Apache PDFBox not able to extract text, but PDFBox Debugger showing the text correctly?
I am not able to extract text from a pdf, it is showing garbage characters, but when I checked with the debugger, it was showing the correct text.
Here is the pdf link.
Let's say I am trying to extract page 9 using PDFTextStripper, I get output like following:
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhIhhIhhhhhhhhhIh]hhhhhIhhIIhhIIIhhhh...

I also get same results when try to copy using Adobe Reader, or extract using other libraries Itext, MuPdf.
However, when checked by PDFBox Debugger, I see the text is correctly visible as follows (highlighted red):

I don't have knowledge of the PDF stream syntax above, but if the PDFBox Debugger is showing correct text, why can't PDFBox able to extract the text correctly?
Also, the font used is an old Gurmukhi script font, in which the glyphs are drawn in the ASCII range mostly, hence the text is English letters.

Before unicode fonts became popular, these type of fonts were used, so mapping is known and also Gurbani Lipi font is easily available.

@KJ However, as I said the debugger is showing the correct output, its is not showing h's. One more thing I tried is using pdf2ps on the same page 9 and in the output file also the text is correct, so I am still confused why when extracting the issue is coming?

you should not look into language, as I said, it's an old font, so the text is actually in ascii letters, but when used with the font, it displays gurmukhi script. If you see the picture I have shared, I would expect correct output something like: RI vwih gurU jI, after I have got the text correctly, I can easily transliterate them into unicode letters. If you want to try, you can also either open the pdf in debugger, or convert it into ps, and check the mappings of each h with the shown ascii letters.

I have debugged further into code, and it appears to CMAP issue, the code point is correct, however when converting to unicode, the font mapping is wrong...

Look at the /ToUnicode stream of the first font at Root/Pages/Kids/[2]/Kids/[0]/Kids/[0]/Kids/[0]/Kids/[2]/Resources/Font/R16/ToUnicode. Many different values are mapped to the same value, e.g. <0068>, <0049> or <0029>.

So now I have found the issue, how to fix the mapping? Given I have the original font..

Well, If the To Unicode stream is the culprit, have you tried to remove it yet?

The issue was incorrect char code mapping to unicode by the font...
However, using the char codes directly in processTextPosition is working for me:
@Override
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
{
    super.processTextPosition(text);

    // following gives incorrect mapping
    // String unicode = text.getUnicode();

    int[] cc = text.getCharacterCodes();
    String unicode = new String(cc, 0, cc.length);
}

See official example for more on usage of processTextPosition.
